# What is the resourceId parameter when trying to get virtual machines attached to an environment?

Tags: azure-devops-rest-api

I am currently trying to grab the tags associated with the with a specific VM in a given environment. The problem is, I can't figure out what the resourceId parameter stands for.

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/virtualmachines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0), I should be able to grab all the machines associated with the environment. Although for the life of me, I can't figure out what the resourceId stands for. The call would look something like this:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{environmentId}/providers/virtualmachinegroups/{resourceId}/virtualmachines?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

All of the other parameters I can understand, but not resourceId. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The document "[**Virtualmachines - List**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/distributedtask/virtualmachines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.1)" seems have some issues and need to be updated.

To list the Virtualmachines in an environment, you can try the following endpoint.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/environments/{environmentId}/providers/virtualmachines?api-version=6.1-preview.1
```

I have tested this endpoint on my side, it can work fine.

**[UPDATE]**

The required scope should be "**Environment (Read & manage)**". I have tested the PAT that only contains this scope to execute the API, it can work fine and return the list of the Virtual machines in the specified environment. When creating a PAT, you also need to make sure the Organization scope has contained the organization which the API is running for.

[image]

And also make sure the PAT has not expired.

Comment: How did you discover the /pipelines/environments endpoint? In the latest docs, environments are under the /distributedtask/environments endpoint, however the API for getting resources via the resource ID appears to be broken.

Comment: Is it possible to expand this API call, so that the response includes agent capabilities similar to `?includeCapabilities=true` or `$expand=capabilities` in other endpoints?

Comment: Is there any .NET namespace or method available to call the same API ?

Answer (score 0):

I also found out that you could query the following addresses, for the same result:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/environments/{envid}?expands=resourceReferences
```

and

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/distributedtask/environments/{envid}?expands=resourceReferences
```

This would result in the list of resources with their tags.

I am not completely sure if it the same thing as Bright's answer, since there is no reference to the type of the resource (virtual machine/kubernetes) in the call.

Comment: I tried calling your APIs, and it seems that we are not receiving tags properly. Additionally, the status of environment agents, such as whether they are online or offline, is not available. If someone else requires this functionality as well, it's worth noting that the API provided by Bright appears to be perfect.