# Azure DevOps - Cannot find .NET namespace or library for querying the status of Environment agents

Tags: c#, .net, rest, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I am attempting to retrieve the status of Environment agents using Microsoft's C# .NET libraries.

```
public EnvironmentInstance ReadEnvironment(string environmentName)
        {
            VssConnection vssConnection = GetVssConnection();

            TaskAgentHttpClient taskAgentHttpClient = vssConnection.GetClient<TaskAgentHttpClient>();

            var matchingEnv = taskAgentHttpClient.GetEnvironmentsAsync(Settings.TfsProjectName, environmentName).Result;
            var envDetails = taskAgentHttpClient.GetEnvironmentByIdAsync(Settings.TfsProjectName, matchingEnv[0].Id, EnvironmentExpands.ResourceReferences).Result;
            
            return envDetails;
        }
```

It looks like the method that I'm using doesn't return the agent status in envDetails.

I got a REST API(GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/environments/{environmentId}/providers/virtualmachines?api-version=6.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/environments/%7BenvironmentId%7D/providers/virtualmachines?api-version=6.1-preview.1)) to get all the required details, but I'm unable to locate the corresponding class or method in azure devops .net libraries.

Refer below posts that says the Environment APIs are not working properly:

[1] Issue Thread - https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/unable-to-get-virtual-machine-using-taskagent-c-cl/1109622

[2] Workaround Thread - [What is the resourceId parameter when trying to get virtual machines attached to an environment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66817452/what-is-the-resourceid-parameter-when-trying-to-get-virtual-machines-attached-to)

**I need the corresponding class or method in [azure devops .net libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/?view=azure-devops-dotnet) that calls below API:**

GET [https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/environments/{environmentId}/providers/virtualmachines?api-version=6.1-preview.1](https://dev.azure.com/%7Borganization%7D/%7Bproject%7D/_apis/pipelines/environments/%7BenvironmentId%7D/providers/virtualmachines?api-version=6.1-preview.1)